# Does ipython notebook have a %%latex magic cell?

Tags: latex, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to render come complex maths in an ipython notebook at came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13208286/how-to-write-latex-in-ipython-notebook/13222501#13222501) and this [ipython notebook demonstrating the Rich Display System (scroll down to the bottom is is the last example)](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/url/github.com/ipython/ipython/raw/master/examples/notebooks/Part%205%20-%20Rich%20Display%20System.ipynb) which both mention the availability of a `%%latex` cell. However, I get the following error when trying to make a latex cell,

> ERROR: Cell magic function `%%latex` not found.

I am running version 0.13.2, I am missing something? Do I need to import this magic function somehow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`%%latex` Magic has been written during  SciPy 12", and `0.13` was already released at this date (actually SciPy 12" was the reason to release...). As `0.13.x` with `x>0` are only bugfixes, chances are great that it didn't made its way in it. You should be able to backport, the code is dead simple, but need to be adapted as Magic System changed slightly (`IPython/core/magics/display.py`, boilerplate removed):

```
@cell_magic
def latex(self, line, cell):
    """Render the cell as a block of latex"""
    display(Latex(cell))
```

Comment: Hello @matt, thanks for your help. I will try to apply those changes. I went into the ipython code I could find a display.py file in the IPython/core/magics directory. I looked both on github master and 0.13.2. Any ideas?

Comment: [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/core/magics/display.py#L40) on master , and [the 0.13.2 doc](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/reference.html#defining-your-own-magics)

Comment: I don't know how I missed that! Anyway, the solution was easy: just install from the master branch, `pip install git+git://github.com/ipython/ipython.git#egg=ipython --upgrade`

Comment: Yes, that works too, I usually try to assume people don't want to run from master. `setup.py develop` is nice also to just `git pull` and be up to date without reinstalling.