# Inline math mode on iPython notebook

Tags: latex, ipython, jupyter-notebook, mathjax

In iPython notebook, how can I write a mathematic formula such as `r^2` in a line (inline math mode in latex vocabulary). ie. Is it possible to not go on a new line when the formula is printed.

If like in LaTeX, it should be `\(r^2\)` but it doesn't work...

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In a markdown cell you can use $s, e.g. $r^2$. This requires MathJax from CDN or a local MathJax installation. If you have an internet connection it should work right out of the box.

see e.g. [Typesetting Equations](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/4.0.x/examples/Notebook/Typesetting%20Equations.ipynb) example notebook

Comment: The link is broken. Could you provide a new one?

Comment: @theSage Thanks, for the hint! I've updated the link.