# Latex with IPython (IPython) error

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex, ipython

While trying to use LaTeX with IPython, I used the following code:

```
from IPython.display import display, Math, Latex
display(Math(r'F(k) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) e^{2\pi i k} dx'))
```

from [How to write LaTeX in IPython Notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13208286/how-to-write-latex-in-ipython-notebook).

But, I got the following error.

```
<IPython.core.display.Math at 0x269a030>
```

What does this error mean? When do I get it? How can I get rid of it?

Comment: That's not an error. It's the printable representation of an object.

Comment: You need to run it in an ipython notebook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not an error. Run it with `ipython notebook` and you will see [your integral displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tB2se.jpg).

Comment: is there a way to get it displayed pretty in regular visual studio code?

Comment: Not my area of expertise but it looks like the Quarto exrension can render in VS Code. https://quarto.org/docs/tools/vscode.html

Answer (score 0):

It is not an error, it is the output representation. Simply run the code inside the IPython notebook:

```
from IPython.display import display, Math, Latex
display(Math(r'F(k) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) e^{2\pi i k} dx'))
```