# Display an astropy Quantity within a LaTeX string

Tags: python, latex, jupyter-notebook, astropy

I'm looking for a way to render `astropy` variables inside LaTeX strings within an IPython notebook. For example, given a simple premise,

```
from astropy.constants import c
import astropy.units as u
from astropy import log
```

the speed of light is beautifully rendered by default as:

[image: latex-rendering]

by simply typing it in the ipython prompt. Now, what if I would like to embed this in a string? How to hop on the same rendering train already used by astropy to print an example string like `'Speed limit: {}'.format(c)`?

Everything I've tried so far, including variations of LaTeX-formatted strings, only displays an ASCII string as an output:
[image: ascii-rendering]

Comment: This is effectively a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13208286/how-to-write-latex-in-ipython-notebook See the accepted answer there.

Comment: I disagree. The answer you linked explains how to use ipython display function to print latex code, and would not produce an acceptable output for, e.g., `display(Math('{}'.format(c)))`. This question asks specifically for how to expand latex functionality already present in the `astropy.units` module to a more general case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is probably a more elegant solution, but this works:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```py
# Science
import numpy as np
from astropy.units import Unit

# Notebook
from IPython.display import Markdown
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"

# Handy functions
def Qshow(Q, sigfig=2, unit=None, name=None):
    name = Q.info.name
    if unit is not None:
        Q = Q.to(unit)
    if sigfig is not None:
        q = Q.round(sigfig - int(np.log10(Q.value)))
    else:
        q = Q
    if name is not None:
        output = Markdown(f'{name} = {q._repr_latex_()}')
    else:
        output = Markdown(f'{q._repr_latex_()}')
    return output

# Parameter
density = 1.23456e12 * Unit('g/cm^3')
density.info.name = r'$\rho$'

# Results
Qshow(density)
```

[image]

See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/Miladiouss/fb06d9e08efdb24f8c8a45c8b6fea503) for latest version.