# Google Colab API

Tags: google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

Is there a Google Colab API? I'm looking to accomplish things like:

1. Create users
2. Create notebooks
3. Share notebooks with users
4. Retrieve the contents of a notebook

Answer (score 42, accepted):

As pointed out in the other answer, Colab Notebooks are files on your Google Drive. Hence, sharing them or retrieving their contents can be done via the [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) (from what I understand you can use the [webContentLink](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#webContentLink) to download it).

However, your first question is:

## Where is the Google Colab API?

For anyone coming here from Google trying to find the official Google Colab API (because it's one of the top results when googling for now), here is the answer:

[As of summer 2020] Since this is merely a research project, there is no official API documentation and very limited documentation.

## Official Documentation (very limited)

- [Google Colab: Official FAQ](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html)
- The [Google Colab: Official Feature Demo](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/basic_features_overview.ipynb#scrollTo=Id6tDF1HQSHD) exemplifies most features. Use it to learn many of its capabilities.

## The API in code

Beyond those resources, your best bet would be going to the [Official Github Repository](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools). Here are some highlights from the code:

- [Github: `google.colab`](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/tree/master/google/colab)
- [Github: `google.colab.drive`](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/blob/master/google/colab/drive.py)
- [Github: `google.colab.drive.mount`](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/blob/master/google/colab/drive.py#L32) (used in quite a few snippets)
- [Github: `google.colab.files`](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/blob/master/google/colab/files.py) (provides `download` and `upload` utilities)
- [Github: `google.colab.snippets`](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/blob/master/google/colab/snippets.py) (add snippets to the snippets list programmatically; FYI: you can  find all snippets by going to `Insert` -> `Snippets`)
- [Github: `all packages`](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/blob/master/google/colab/__init__.py#L20)

## More Notes

The [FAQ](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html) explains many important mechanics. Highlights include:

> It’s a Jupyter notebook environment that requires no setup to use.

Convinient!

I heartly recommend checking out the [Official Feature Demo](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/basic_features_overview.ipynb#scrollTo=Id6tDF1HQSHD); it's how I found out that it even supports LaTeX and MathJax! (but then again that might [not come as news](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13208286/how-to-write-latex-in-ipython-notebook) to someone with experience in [Jupyter](https://jupyter-notebook-beginner-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/what_is_jupyter.html))

### Virtual Machine

The FAQ also mentions...

> Code is executed in a virtual machine dedicated to your account. Virtual machines are recycled when idle for a while, and have a maximum lifetime enforced by the system.

That is why you can execute all kinds of the usual system calls (e.g. `!pip install`, `open` etc.) and it just works.

However that is also why when you come back the next day...

1. `drive.mount` asks for your permission again
2. you have to re-install all packages
3. any newly created files are all gone (unless you put em in a drive-mounted folder)

Answer (score 8):

Google Colab Notebooks are just like a normal file in Google Drive.

So, you can use Drive API to manage them just like any Drive files.

For example, you can share notebooks with Drive REST API as documented here

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-sharing