# Is there A google Colab API or A way to create one

Tags: python, api, web-services, google-colaboratory, remoting

Hi I am planning to create a app that will use Google Colab is there any existing API for this and if not how can I make one? Here are the requirements that I need the API to do

```
1. create a notebook and paste some code then run it
2.print the feedback to the user of the App
3.Upload a file from the users pc and download files on the users computer
4.Not show any of this on the user side
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Colab API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50595831/google-colab-api)

Comment: no not really .

Answer (score 1):

I'll redirect you to this Stack Overflow question since its the same than yours :)

[Google Colab Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50595831/google-colab-api)