# How can I open Google Colab files in Neovim?

Tags: google-colaboratory, integration, neovim

I am looking for a way to open [Google Colab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Jupyter#Industry_adoption) files in Neovim. I am basically trying to figure out a way to connect the two platforms since I have to work on Google Colab for some [CUDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA)-related assignment stuff and I just love Neovim. By doing this, I would also be able to use Neovim cheat sheets, [GitHub Copilot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub_Copilot) and other productivity tools.

How can it be done?

Comment: I know this isn't a full-fledged solution, but here is an interesting thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50595831/google-colab-api

If you can find a way to mount the files on your system using google drive, you could probably open them with nvim?

Comment: Something like [jupyter-acending](https://github.com/untitled-ai/jupyter_ascending) which allows syncing and everything for Google Colab would be highly beneficial. But yess, there are some plugins for (neo)vim to work with ipynb files, Let me know if someone has tried this plugin, [vim-jukit](https://github.com/luk400/vim-jukit) else I'll update here once I get a chance to try that.

Comment: [The bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75274341/timeline) attracted a [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) plagiariser.