# How to keep the fraction in the output without evaluating

Tags: python, sympy

I try to find out the **Characteristic Polynomial** and **Eigen values** using `sympy`. But when I print the results in Jupyter notebook all the fractions in the coefficients of the polynomials have been evaluated as `float`(e.g-`0.5x**2+1)` but I want `$(1/2)x^2+1$)`. Is there anything to solve this problem. Thank you.

**My Code**

```
import sympy as sp
from sympy import *
x, y, z = symbols('x,y,z')
init_printing(use_unicode=False, wrap_line=False)
M = sp.Matrix([[0, -1/2], [1/3, 0]])
x = symbols('x')
p = M.charpoly(x)
p
```

**Output.**

[image: Output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

these are the relevant chages

```
from fractions import Fraction
M = sp.Matrix([[0, -Fraction(1, 2)], [Fraction(1, 3), 0]])
```

which yield

```
PurePoly(x**2 + 1/6, x, domain='QQ')
```

the point is that `1/3` is immediately converted to the `float` 0.3333... the way to avoid that is to use [`fractions.Fraction`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html?module-fractions) or (probably better) the sympy version thereof: [`sympy.Rational`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html?rational#rational).

Comment: this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13208286/how-to-write-latex-in-ipython-notebook .