# Correctly display LaTeX expression within a pandas DataFrame on a Jupyter Notebook

Tags: pandas, latex, ipython, jupyter

If I try the code from the accepted answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64721893/latex-formula-in-pandas-dataframe), it works fine on my local Jupyter Lab but unfortunately not on Google Colab.

Any idea why is this?

Jupyter Lab:
[image]

Google Colab:
[image]

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Please check this answer and see if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49573644/rendering-latex-in-output-cells-in-colaboratory

Comment: @Jayvee that works for simple LaTeX expressions, but unfortunately it does not deal with them inside pandas DataFrames