# Latex expressions in lists

Tags: python, latex, ipython

I am trying to create a list in Python wherein the elements are Latex entries. I have the following code snippet. I have called "from IPython.display import display, Math, Latex".

```
lst = [r'$a_1$', r'$a_2$', r'$a_3$', r'$a_4$']
print(lst)
```

I get ['$a_1$', '$a_2$', '$a_3$', '$a_4$'], but the elements are not "Latexed". Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this can help: [How to write LaTeX in IPython Notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13208286/how-to-write-latex-in-ipython-notebook)

Specifically to your problem: you are trying to display a *list* of latex-formatted strings, which its *not* a latex formatted string itself; a possible workaround could be something like:

```
from IPython.display import display, Math, Latex

class LatexList:

    def __init__(self, lst) :
        self.lst = lst

    def __str__(self) :
        fl = "["
        for exp in self.lst :
            fl += exp+","
        fl += "]"
        return fl

latex_list = LatexList([r'$a_1$', r'$a_2$', r'$a_3$', r'$a_4$'])

display(Math(str(latex_list)))
```

Now it displays a `<IPython.core.display.Math object>`, instead of a list. Of course, how to format the list (i.e. what `__str__` does) is up to you to decide!

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you!  A minor comment: it's better to replace $a_1$ with $$a_1$$.  That gives the subscripts correctly. I think '$a_1$'  is not recognized.